# how to check the value of checkboxes in each row of table dynamically using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table in which values are dynamically added from database as below:

```
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
i = i+1;
// Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the new <tr> element:
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
var cell11 = row.insertCell(10);

// Add some text to the new cells:
cell1.innerHTML = '$name';
cell2.innerHTML = '$name2';
cell3.innerHTML = '$lastname';
cell4.innerHTML = '$lastname2';
cell5.innerHTML = '$mellicode';
cell6.innerHTML = '$estekhdamnum';
cell7.innerHTML = '$email';
cell8.innerHTML = '$username';
cell9.innerHTML = '$password';
cell10.innerHTML = '$id';
var checkbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
checkbox.name = 'checkbox[]';
checkbox.value = 'i-1';
cell11.appendChild(checkbox);
```

I would like to add a button at the end of the table that when I click it, it checks all the check boxes, recognizes the row of the checkbox and do some query.

```
$('tr').click(function(){

});
```

and below is the button that when I click on it, I would like to do the query on checked check boxes.

```
<input type="submit" class="form-control" name = "karbar" value=""onclick="add_karbar()"/><br><br>
```

I shouldn't use 'tr' here I think but I don't know how to recognize the check boxes and see if it is checked or not and recognize the row of the checked checkbox.

thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: You would need to use`.each()` inside your click event to iterate through the checkboxes. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: please tell me how should it be done exactly
I sent my button and I would like to know what is the exact function which should be written

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for,

```js
$("#check").click(function() {
  var index = [];
  $("#table tbody input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(el) {
    index.push($(this).closest('tr').index());
  });
  console.log(index)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="check">
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this.

```js
// Click event on button
$('#checker').click(function(){
  // iterate through all checkboxes that are checked
  $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
    // debugging purposes only
    console.log($(this).val() + " is checked");
    // Add your code here
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="1" checked>1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="2" checked>2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" value="3" checked>3
<button id="checker">Check</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked but how can I run a php code to connect to database using this code?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Your question said you were already getting data from the database. Please show your PHP code and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: $query = "UPDATE users SET admin = 1 WHERE id='value'";
    $rss = mysql_query($query, $conn);
    if($rss){
        echo("alert('successfully updated');");
    }else{
        echo("alert('couldn't update)");
    }

Comment: this is what I am trying to do